# Extra parameter in service reference

Tags: c#, wcf

I use below code for use service reference :

```
var myService = new MyService.MyServiceClient();
myService.DeleteOCDFCompleted += MyServiceDeleteOCDFComplete;
myService.DeleteOCDF(OCDF.OcdfId);

void MyServiceDeleteOCDFComplete(object sender, MyService.DeleteOCDFCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//  OCDFList.Remote(**ocdf that deleted**);
  MessageBox.Show("Delete Completed successfully.");
}
```

I want Remove deleted object from my list but how can determine deleted parameter in `MyServiceDeleteOCDFComplete` function.

in other word : how can send extra parameter to service reference events.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the additional parameter to the `DeleteOCDF` method (called `userState`). That parameter can be any object, and it will be passed to the event handler, in its `UserState` property.

```
var myService = new MyService.MyServiceClient();
myService.DeleteOCDFCompleted += MyServiceDeleteOCDFComplete;
myService.DeleteOCDF(OCDF.OcdfId, OCDF.OcdfId);

void MyServiceDeleteOCDFComplete(object sender, MyService.DeleteOCDFCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    int ocdfId = (int)e.UserState;
    MessageBox.Show("Delete Completed successfully.");
}
```